# Eloquent как сделать update значений из массива одним запросом?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, update, eloquent

Имею массив данных, к примеру:

```
$arr = [
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => 'value3',
];
```

И есть колонка в таблице с такими значениями:

```
column_name
key1
key2
key3
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы  в данной колонке все значения **key поменялись на значения value** из массива?
Рабочий способ такой:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    EloqModel::where('column_name', $key)
        ->update(['column_name' => $value]);
}
```

Но в этом случае, если в массиве будет как у меня 30000 значений, будет выполнено 30000 запросов, что не очень хорошо.
Как это всё дело оптимизировать или выполнить одним запросом?

Comment: Так как у вас есть ключ, по которому производится выборка, то массово, кроме как компоновкой в одну транзакцию, через Eloquent не получится (да и вообще кроме как костылять в SQL этого не достичь). Смотрите в сторону DB::beginTransaction и DB::commit. SQL UPDATE оперирует на одном ключе и одним/нескольким значениям для него, но не наоборот.

Comment: @u_mulder никакая, в mysql к примеру может быть не более 4096 столбцов на таблицу. автор все же имел в виду 30к строк и обновить надо один столбец по ключу

Comment: что-то мне кажется, тут проще сделать вставку во временную таблицу и апдейт через джойн.